Triggering Jenkins pipeline through PR Create trigger in BitBucket
I am trying to trigger a Jenkins pipeline using webhooks in BitBucket so that whenever a PR is opened from any branch into main (or vice versa), the pipeline is triggered.
I have set up the webhook to trigger when I create a PR (and it is) however, the problem that I am facing is in setting up the BitBucket Push and Pull request hook plug-in which is currently not triggering the pipeline despite the request being published and am unable to pinpoint where the error might be.
Also note: I do not have the BitBucket plugin installed alongside this one as explicitly mentioned by the documentation and the credentials used throughout have been a generated BitBucket App password through access management in Personal settings.
I have set up the plug-in build trigger inside my pipeline as follows:
Plugin setup in pipeline settings
And configured my system settings inside Jenkins like this:
System setting configuration for plugin
And my pipeline is a simple Jenkinsfile that prints the environment variables:
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Print Environment Variables') {
            steps {
                bat 'set'
            }
        }
    }
}

